# Changing row colour with an onClick in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, row

how do I change the background colour of a row when I click on some text within it? I am simply wanting to highlight that row. I've added an onclick event but no idea how to light up the row. Here's what I have..

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gdvOrders" width="100%" runat="server" style="font-size:1.8em" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No orders" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="orderID" DataSourceID="DSOrders" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>  

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtn1" onclick="LnkBtn1_Click" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ordertext") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
.........
```

VB

```
Protected Sub LnkBtn1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

     Dim LnkBtn1 As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)

End Sub
```

Comment: As an aside... If all you want to do is change the color of an element, this would be *a lot* easier to do in JavaScript, rather than posting back to the server and re-rendering the entire page.

Comment: Thanks, yes that would be certainly be much better but I'm only just learning VB/Asp.Net and don't know where to start with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's write some code to highlight the row using vb. As pointed out, this is a kind of using a "mountain" to drop on a small ant of a problem. (much better to do this client side).

However, let's do this with server-side code, since there are MANY things to be learned from this example. (such as picking up the current row in a GridView based on button click).

So, while 100% client-side JavaScript is a great idea, it can often not be all that simple, since the previous row that is highlighted now has to be un-highlighted!

So, say this simple GridView with a button in the row.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
            Width="50%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Descriptioin" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="130px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Select"
                            OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And code behind to load up this grid:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GVHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And also note in above, we have a standard button in the GridView

And that button can have this code:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    gRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue

    If ViewState("LastRow") IsNot Nothing Then
        ' we have to un-highligt the previous row
        Dim RowIX As Integer = ViewState("LastRow")
        Dim gRow2 As GridViewRow = GVHotels.Rows(RowIX)
        gRow2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    End If

    ViewState("LastRow") = gRow.RowIndex

End Sub
```

So, note how when we highlight a row, we ALSO have to un-highlight the previous row.

The effect now looks like this:

[image]

However, perhaps it of greater ease to just let the cursor "hover" over the row. Note how the above grid already has a "hover" built int.

That code free row hover effect was done with this setting of the GridView:

```
CssClass="table table-hover"
```

So, in fact, table, and table-hover are bootstrap classes, and assuming that you have bootstrap installed (you VERY likely do, since that is the default for templates), then perhaps just a cursor hover will suffice.

As noted, note how the row button click picks up the CURRENT row clicked on by using naming container. This works for repeaters, GridView, ListView and more. This approach also means you don't have to use or care about specific GridView events such as command name. In fact, for such row clicks, I suggest you use the above naming container for such events.

## Edit: Allow a re-load and re-bind of Grid, keeping rows.

So, to allow/keep the highlighted rows EVEN with a re-load?

Then we need 2 new parts:

First part, keep a list of the primary key values from the database.

Second part, add to the re-bind routine code to highlight any existing row in our list of rows.

So, code now becomes this:

```
Dim MyIDList As New List(Of Integer)
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()      ' first time grid load
        ViewState("IDList") = MyIDList
    Else
        MyIDList = ViewState("IDList")
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GVHotels.DataBind()

End Sub


Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim PK As Integer = GVHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex)("ID")

    If MyIDList.Contains(PK) Then
        ' ROW WAS Highliged, remove from list and un-highlight
        MyIDList.Remove(PK)
        gRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Else
        ' not in our list, add to light, and highlight row
        MyIDList.Add(PK)
        gRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GVHotels_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim PKID As Integer = GVHotels.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex)("ID")
        If MyIDList.Contains(PKID) Then
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue
        End If

    End If


End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    LoadData()

End Sub
```

So, the last button is to test our code, and it does a 100% re-load.

The results are this:

[image]

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you. I have enough to work with now. I am wanting to highlight multiple rows, so I deleted the Un-Highlight code and it worked a treat. Then I have added an IF statement to check if a selected row is already highlighted and if it is, then it unhighlights it when selected. My only problem now is that this webpage refreshes every 60 seconds so it can update with live orders. Then however, it forgets what's highlighted when it refreshes and resets back to everything being unhighlighted. Is there an easy way to make it retain it's state?

Comment: Well,  as the existing sample shows, the highlight of the grid DOES survive a post back. (that's why we had code to un-highlight the previous row!!!). So, the persisting of the row highlight does work, and is 100% fine. However, what is NOT going to be fine is if you re-load and re-bind the GridView. In that case, all bets are off, since a re-load of the GV is a 100% re-create and re-binding (and thus any formatting is lost). The solution THEN means we need to keep/persit/maintain a list of "id" values that have been previous selected. So state is saved until you blow out and re-load gv

Comment: Ah yeah it needs to re-load the GV so I will try get it to save the highlighted state in the database and have it reload when it refreshes. You have definitely helped me with a lot which I was struggling though, so I have marked this as answered. Thank you so much again for your help.

Comment: Ok see my 2nd edit. I show how to manage your issue, and still allow a 100% re-load, but keeping rows highlihged....

Answer (score 1):

I do that kind of stuff during the Pre-Render event. Here's a small snippet.

```
Private Sub gdvOrders_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gdvOrders.PreRender

    Dim GV As GridView = If(sender Is Nothing, gdvOrders, sender)

    '...

    For Each GvRow As GridViewRow In GV.Rows

        GvRow.Cells(0).Style.Add("text-align", "right")
        GvRow.Cells(1).Style.Add("text-align", "right")

        With GvRow.Cells(0).Style
            .Add("border-left-style", "solid")
            .Add("border-left-width", "2px")
            .Add("border-left-color", "Black")
        End With

        With GvRow.Cells(1).Style
            .Add("border-left-style", "solid")
            .Add("border-left-width", "2px")
            .Add("border-left-color", "Black")
        End With

        GvRow.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray
        GvRow.Cells(1).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```